# Laravel Form $request input value of 0 turns NULL while trying to update

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel Form with a input field percentage (defined as `$table->decimal('percent', 5, 2);`).

If user enter values like 1 , 2, 2.04, 8.97, 100.00, 88.00. everything goes thru.
Even when user enters 0.00 everything updates properly.

but when user enters 0, before updating the record it fails as that 0 (actually it is '0' string) is turned into `null` in the SQL that is being executed and because field is non null-able it gives me SQL error.

Is this expected or am I missing something here?

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 0):

Try to use isnull check

```
isnull(value,0) as value
```

or

```
coalesce(value, 0) as value;
```

in your sql query.

Comment: OK, the sql query is not created by me, it is created by laravel, eloquent to be precise.  I need something in php.